# Core Data concurrency - NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, concurrency

So I need to use cora-data managed object context using multiple thread.
I found the below implementation to be pretty much what I need.
I have 2 question :

1. Where do I release the MOC that I allocate ? I don't want to go through every function thread in my app and to call a function to release the MOC.
   I'd rather write the function, and somehow make it so it be called by every thread prior to his exit. is that possible ?
2. Is the below implementation enough for core data concurrency ?

   ```
   -(void) StoreManagedObjectContextForCurrentThread:(NSManagedObjectContext*) context
   {
       [[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] setObject: context forKey: AQPerThreadManagedObjectContext];
   }


   -(NSManagedObjectContext *) myManagedObjectContext {


       NSManagedObjectContext * result = [[[NSThread currentThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey: AQPerThreadManagedObjectContext];
       if ( result != nil )
           return result;

       NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
       if (coordinator!=nil)
       {
           NSManagedObjectContext * moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
           [moc setMergePolicy: NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy];
           [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator: coordinator];
           [self StoreManagedObjectContextForCurrentThread:moc];
           [moc release];      // now owned by the thread dictionary
           return moc;
       }

       return nil;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the implementation you've provided, you haven't got a way to release the managed object context before the thread disappears, because its lifetime is dictated by the thread dictionary, and *that* object's lifetime is handled by Foundation, not by you.

If you want to manage the objects' lifetimes, you need to manage their storage. That means moving away from using `-threadDictionary`. One option is to implement your background work as `NSOperation` subclasses and keep the managed object contexts around for the lifetime of the operations, but that's likely a big change from what you currently have.

Comment: Yep, but just to make sure, when the thread exist it will free the dictionary and everything within(including my MOC) right ? I won't have a memory leak I hope.

Comment: @Idan: correct. The thread dictionary disappears at the end of the thread's life (well, more specifically, when the `NSThread` object itself is deallocated).